# Pivot, Unpivot, Cross Apply?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Say I have data like the below and what I really want is to (pivot?) AssigedType as columns (Handling, Supervising, etc.) although I don't think pivot is the right way to go as I'm not aggregating anything. There'll be three tables involved: Matters, MattersProfessionals, Professionals), i.e.

Matters.Matters = MattersProfessionals.Matters
Professionals.Professionals = Matters.Professionals

```html
matterid    AssignedType    ProfName
27391-0001001   Handling    Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0051001   Handling    Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0051001   Supervising Skip A. Lawyer
18814-0226WO1   Handling    Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0050001   Handling    Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0050001   Supervising Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0053001   Supervising Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0053001   Handling    Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0052001   Handling    Skip A. Lawyer
37085-0052001   Supervising Skip A. Lawyer
18814-0226AU1   Handling    Skip A. Lawyer
```

Desired output:

```
MatterID       Handling        Supervising 
27391-0001001  Skip A. Lawyer  Skip A.Lawyer 
etc...
```

Like a pivot but without the aggregation?

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: Where the value of AssignedType is a column name, and where ProfName is the value, along side MatterID (Matters.MatterID)

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Can you try to explain that more clearly?

Comment: Using the data I supplied as an example:

Columns: MatterID, Handling, Supervising

Row Values: 27391-0001001, Skip A. Lawyer, Skip A.Lawyer

Like a pivot but without the aggregation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: What you want is some kind of pivot transformation. The post I marked as duplicate applies to your question.

Comment: Pivot presumes aggregation, doesn't?

Comment: Aggregates can be MAX or MIN too. They don't have to be SUM.

Comment: @StevenMpls Yes, but you can use `max()` to aggregate and chose the non-null value. The highest voted answer in the linked question shows this.

Answer (score 0):

Min() or Max() can also be aggregations for your pivot function:

```
SELECT * from (<here the original select goes>) 
AS source
PIVOT 
    (min(ProfName) For AssignedType in ([Handling], [Supervising])) 
AS y;
```

This would return a table like

```
matterid       Handling        Supervising     
-------------  --------------  --------------  
27391-0001001  Skip A. Lawyer  (null)          
37085-0051001  Skip A. Lawyer  Skip A. Lawyer  
...
```